# Automatically iconize all Associations in output cells

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, associations, hold, iconize

I work with expressions containing large associations (`<|…|>`) as subexpressions, and I want to automatically iconize all such subexpressions in all output cells in `StandardForm` (which is the default form I use). But want it to only affect typesetting, I don't want `IconizedObject` wrappers to be inserted if I edit any output cell and it's converted into an input. Also, I don't want to see `Iconize` or `IconizedObject` wrappers in output cells in other forms, such as `InputForm` or `FullForm`. My first attempt was

```
$PrePrint = # /. a_?AssociationQ :> Iconize[a] &;
```

and it failed on several points. First, I can see unwanted `IconizedObject` in `InputForm`:

```
{<|1 -> 2|>} // InputForm
(* {IconizedObject[<|1 -> 2|>, Automatic, Method -> Automatic]} *)
```

Moreover, output cells containing associations under `Hold` or `Function` show an unwanted `Iconize` wrapper literally instead of actually iconizing its argument (or, at least, leaving it as is):

```
Hold[<|1 -> 2|>]
(* {Hold[Iconize[Association[1 -> 2]]] *)

<|3 -> 4|> &
(* Iconize[Association[3 -> 4]] & *)
```

And, finally and more concerning, there is an evaluation leak that can modify variables, and inserts `Iconize` in a wrong place:

```
ClearAll[x];
Hold[x = <||>]
(* Hold[Iconize[x = Association[]]] *)

ValueQ[x]
(* True *)

Head[x]
(* Association *)
```

How can I fix all these issues?

---

*Update:* I found that some of the issues can be fixed using

```
$PrePrint = # /. {x_InformationData :> x, 
     a_Association :> With[{icon = Iconize[Unevaluated[a]]}, icon /; True]} &;
```

although I do not entirely understand why it works that way.

---

*Update 2:* Here is a different approach that seems to work, although I haven't tested it thoroughly yet. Do you know of any problems it might cause?

```
Unprotect[Association];
Format[a_Association, StandardForm] := Iconize[Unevaluated[a]];
Protect[Association];
```

Comment: I read you post and was going to propose `Format`, which is my go-to solution for custom output, though I have not used it for built-in symbols. Update 2 sounds good to me and (+1).